# Exclude Characters using Preg_Match

Tags: php, regex

```
var slideshow_photos = [


"http://domain/2294484.jpg"



, "http://domain/2294485.jpg"



, "http://domain/2294488.jpg"

];
</script>
<!-- begin
```

I only need the urls as:

```
http://domain/2294485.jpg
http://domain/3155485.jpg
```

and so on.

How can i do it?

My attempt:

```
preg_match('#var slideshow_photos = \[\s*"(.*?)"\s*];#s', $contentPage, $links);
```

Output:

```
echo $links[1];
```

Sample Result:

```
[1] => http://domain/3527069.jpg" , "http://domain/3324894.jpg)
```

Any idea?

This is a rough quick task...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Check this out It works fine with your result**

```
<?php
$contentpage = '<SCRIPT language="javascript" type="text/javascript"> 
        var slideshow_photos = ["http://domain/2294484.jpg","http://domain/2294485.jpg","http://domain/2294488.jpg"];
        /*for($i=0;$i<slideshow_photos.length;$i++){
            $urls =  document.write(slideshow_photos[$i]);  
        }*/

    </SCRIPT>';
preg_match('#var slideshow_photos = \[\s*"(.*?)"\s*];#s',$contentpage, $links);
$data = str_replace('"','',$links[1]);
$dataArray = explode(',',$data);
foreach($dataArray as $key=>$value):
    echo $dataArray[$key]."<br/>";  
endforeach;
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have ungreedy quantifiers by default. Try removing the `?` in `(.*?)`.

If that doesn't work, try using `([^"]*)` instead of `(.*?)`.

Answer (score 0):

Easiest is to grab the inner contents of `[]` and then parse that out with `explode()`:

```
$links = array();
preg_match('/slideshow_photos = \[([^]]+)\]/', $contentPage, $matches);
$matches = explode(',', $matches[1]);
foreach ($matches as $link) {
  // Trim off the whitespace and quotes
  $links[] = trim($link, " \"\n");
}
var_dump($links);

array(3) {
  [0]=>
  string(25) "http://domain/2294484.jpg"
  [1]=>
  string(25) "http://domain/2294485.jpg"
  [2]=>
  string(25) "http://domain/2294488.jpg"
}
```

This could all be crammed into a regular expression, but this is a procedural alternative.

#### Update:

Here's a regex-only solution that does the job.  The expression `http[^"]+"` finds `http` and everything following it up to the next `"` double quote.

```
$links = array();
preg_match_all('/(http[^"]+)"/', $contentPage, $links);

var_dump($links[1]);
array(3) {
    [0]=>
    string(25) "http://domain/2294484.jpg"
    [1]=>
    string(25) "http://domain/2294485.jpg"
    [2]=>
    string(25) "http://domain/2294488.jpg"
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is complete working code

I have split the match in two steps, in the first step I got the urls list part string and in the next step, I have splitted the urls. Hope this helps

```
<?php

$fullStr = <<<REGEX
var slideshow_photos = [


"http://domain/2294484.jpg"



, "http://domain/2294485.jpg"



, "http://domain/2294488.jpg"

];
REGEX;

$urlsStrPattern = '#var slideshow_photos = \[\s*?(".*?")\s*];#s';
$urlsPattern = '#"(.*?)"#s';

$urlsStrMatch;
preg_match($urlsStrPattern,$fullStr,$urlsStrMatch);

var_dump($urlsStrMatch[1]);

$urlsListMatch;
preg_match_all($urlsPattern,$urlsStrMatch[1],$urlsListMatch);

var_dump($urlsListMatch[1]);



?>
```

Output

```
string '"http://domain/2294484.jpg"



, "http://domain/2294485.jpg"



, "http://domain/2294488.jpg"' (length=101)

array
  0 => string 'http://domain/2294484.jpg' (length=25)
  1 => string 'http://domain/2294485.jpg' (length=25)
  2 => string 'http://domain/2294488.jpg' (length=25)
```